# i'm always getting this error whenever i want to create a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

[this is the error i get whenever i create a react app using create-react-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9APT.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the command which is written and to create a react app, run `npx create-react-app my-app`